# Visual Styles disabled while DWM is working

Tags: c#, windows, dwm, visual-styles

I have an owner-drawing window caption, which I create using C#, Windows Forms, P/Invoking dwmapi.dll and several other windows libs.

To detect if the DWM is enabled, I use the next code:

```
private bool isDwmWindowFramePaintEnabled()
{
    try
    {
        return WinApi.DwmIsCompositionEnabled();
    }
    catch (DllNotFoundException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To paint window caption I use visual style renderer. I paint window caption only when DWM is enabled.
Here is a piece of code:

```
var renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Window.Caption.Active);
WinApi.DrawThemeTextEx(renderer.Handle, memDc, 0, 0, text, -1, uFormat, ref clientRect, ref dttOpts);
```

My code is supposed to work on Windows OS that support Aero themes (7/Vista/8).
Recently I got the next exception in the VisualStyleRender c'tor:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Visual Styles-related operation resulted in an error because visual styles are currently disabled in the client area.
```

The thing happened on Windows 8 OS (6.2.9200.0). When I tested my code, it worked perfectly on any themes on Windows Vista/7/8, including classic ones and high contrast.

So, my question is, why is this happening? Is it possible that visual styles got disabled on Windows 8?
And how should I resolve it? Is there any event that notifies that visual styles got turned off?
I know that I can check if visual styles are enabled by using the property `VisualStyleRenderer.IsSupported`, but I want at least to test my solution. And I don't know how to reproduce the situation.

Comment: Invalid test, use VisualStyleRenderer.IsSupported instead.

Comment: For posterity & anyone finding this question in the context of a related but different problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmiscompositionenabled " As of Windows 8, DWM composition is always enabled. If an app [does not] declare Windows 8 compatibility in their manifest,... Windows 8 compatibility is not assumed and this function receives a value of FALSE"